# JAVA NATIVE INTERFACE IN Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

is java native interface is available is possible using android studio ,if yes any good tutorials to follow .
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html
in this page showing ndk is coming soon in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio supporting is not so powerful like eclipse but ofcourse you can use ndk.

See this links:
http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/
http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/

I think it must help you.